# How to connect to Cloud SQL MySQL database from App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am currently setting up an open-source marketing software called Mautic on App Engine Flexible Environment. However, I'm having trouble with connecting the App Engine to the Cloud SQL MySQL database using MySQLi. Mautic is a PHP application built on top of Symfony. I tried using /cloudsql/<**instance_connection_name**> as the host, but it didn't work.

Does anyone have any experience with deploying Mautic on App Engine or know to address this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Use this code to connect to your database from App Engine:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(null, 'root', 'password', 'db_name',null,'/cloudsql/instance_connection_name');
```